# pwmconfig and psensor linking temperature sensors?

Tags: linux-mint, temperature

When you set up fancontrol using pwmconfig, the temperature sensors come with names such as "hwmon3/temp5_input" whilst in psensor they come with more descriptive names such as "CPU" or "Core1" etc.

How do I map one name to the other?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ... 
"**pwmconfig**" shows "**hwmon2/temp3_input**" as "**40**", and ... 
**Psensor** shows "**Core 2**" as "**40°C**", then ... 
"**hwmon2/temp3_input**" probably refers to "**Core 2**".